# SQL MAX( ) function

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table MATCHES(OPPONENT, DATE, GOALS_FOR, GOALS_AGAINST)

If I want an SQL query which returns the most recent match where GOALS_FOR was greater than 2, then I can use

```
SELECT *
FROM MATCHES
WHERE GOALS_FOR > 2
AND DATE = ( 
SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM MATCHES
WHERE GOALS_FOR > 2)
```

How can I do this without having to rewrite/recompute

```
MATCHES
WHERE GOALS_FOR > 2
```

twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the top 1 order by date desc, example in tsql

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM MATCHES
WHERE GOALS_FOR > 2
ORDER BY DATE Desc
```

(use rownum for oracle, limit for mysql, fetch first for db2, etc)

Comment: This is a simple way to do it, the other answers add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple join it against a subquery that gets the latest `DATE` for every `GOALS_FOR`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    `matches` a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  GOALS_FOR, MAX(DATE) Date
            FROM    `matches`
            WHERE   GOALS_FOR > 2
            GROUP   BY GOALS_FOR
        ) b ON  a.GOALS_FOR = b.GOALS_FOR
                AND a.Date = b.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If your db supports the `WITH` clause you can use that:

```
WITH
matches_over_two_goals_for as (
SELECT *
FROM matches
WHERE goals_for > 2
)
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM matches_over_two_goals_for
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ID or key for the matches? The reason why you need to have GOALS_FOR > 2 more than once is because there can be more than one match on the given date. Therefore the DATE comparison in could provide matches with GOALS_FOR < 3.

If you can rewrite the query like:

`SELECT *
FROM MATCHES
WHERE MATCH_ID = ( 
SELECT MATCH_ID 
FROM MATCHES
WHERE GOALS_FOR > 2
GROUP BY MATCH_ID
HAVING MAX(DATE) = DATE
)`

You get the picture